# Debugging Java project bring me variables blank

Tags: debugging

I have a problem, when i am debugging a project, I don't know why but java debug bring me blank variables.

[image]

Any idea for fix this problem? When I did this capture, Tht program takes a lot of information.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe show us were you put the breakpoint? This determines which variables are being shown.

Comment: Hmm... sorry i can't show the code, if you want i can "recreate" an example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if we cannot see your code, how are supposed to help? Look at this link: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in detail this [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)